Error whilst attempting to train neural network using tensorflow.keras library
I'm working on my first ML deep learning project using tensorflow.keras
it's a simple lottary prediction and I'm using this to build my knowledge after completing on online course.
Input in 90 integer values from 1 to 90.
Output 5 values selected from the 90 values in input.
when performing the fit "model.fit(X, train_output_catg, epochs=50, batch_size=32)"
I encounter the error:
ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None, 5, 90), output.shape=(None, 5)
The ouput layer on my network is :
output layer
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
I'm using the follwoing loss function:
Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
As I have integers I'm converting to categorical values using :
#Change y to categorical
train_output_catg = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y - 1, num_classes=None)
I see what the problem is but I can't understand how to fix it.
My output layer shape is as follows "output.shape=(None, 5)" but my target shape is "target.shape=(None, 5, 90)"
My initial 'X' and'y' arrays were:
Shape of X : (2223, 90)
Shape of y : (2223, 5)
Then on the 'y' array I performed the to_categorical (as above) which turns it into a 3 dimensional array causing a failure as there is a mismatch between the ouput array and the target array.
thank you for any help you can provide.
I was expecting the function tf.keras.utils.to_categorical to give me the same dimension array as my 'y' array but since it's adding an additional dimension I run into the error described above.
